# Play a string containing video data using python

Tags: python, video, pygame, codec

```
import os 
File = open('Path/video_file.webm','rb')
Size = os.path.getsize('Path/video_file.webm')
Data = File.read(Size)
```

How to play the content in 'Data' using python instead of playing video from it's file?   Please help me. I stuck. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use StringIO

You can create a file from text using
`StringIO.StringIO(string)`
Then play it as you would normally

Docs:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html